# Aren't these two duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Is there any U.S. / FAA regulation that could apply for aviation software?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/is-there-any-u-s-faa-regulation-that-could-apply-for-aviation-software)

[Are there any EU/EASA regulations surrounding aviation software?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/are-there-any-eu-easa-regulations-surrounding-aviation-software)

before you answer me that one is for FAA and the other for EASA, as I mention in my [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3411/1467) the documents/regulations for airborne software are shared by the two agencies, the same being valid for the documents cited by Greg in [his](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3409/1467)

I would edit one of the questions to be about airborne and the other about ground/simulation software.
As they stands to me they require the same answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the documents are shared, there's no way for the asker of the question to know that. Similarly if someone comes looking for the relevant documents, they're likely not to look at the answer since the question clearly states FAA.

It may be a duplicate answer, but the question is not, in my opinion.

Comment: Why does it matter that the asker doesn't know the documents are shared? Marking as a duplicate isn't a punishment; it's just a statement that two questions are the same.

Comment: @DavidRicherby; my point is I don't the think the questions are the same just because the answers are.

Comment: What's the point of having two identical sets of answers? How does it benefit the site if somebody's great answer to the USA question doesn't get copied over to the Europe question or vice-versa?

Comment: @DavidRicherby; On this kind of platform we tend to assign answers to questions, not the other way around (thus the occasional identical answer for two different questions would have to be duplicated), but hey that's only my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that, yes, they are duplicates. I don't see any good reason that the first question couldn't be edited to extend it to all jurisdictions; it would be perfectly reasonable for John Doe to answer "In the USA, ...", Jean Deau to say "In Europe..." and so on.

Since most contributors here seem to be either in the US or Europe, I don't think we'd end up with a hundred and fifty answers running the gamut from Afghanistan to Zimbabwe. The only problem I can see is the minor one that SE only allows one answer to be accepted, whereas one might want to accept both John and Jean's answers.

Comment: I do not think that this problem is applicable here, because for this question the two answers would/should be the same, as the FAA vs EASA documents differ only by the identification code.

Comment: Ultimately the referenced documents are likely shared by more than two agencies (I'm sure many nations reference  RTCA DO-178 for example), but the questions being asked are *regulatory*, not *procedural*. RTCA DO-178 provides procedures which are one way (though not the *only* way) to meet specific *regulations* that the FAA and EASA may promulgate.

Comment: While most contributors here are *currently* in the US or Europe, hopefully in time communities will build up from other countries as well.  As you said, you can't accept more than one answer, and people often search for things like:  [faa-regulations] [software] and see what they find.  Since a question can only have 5 tags, it could never be tagged with all of the appropriate jurisdictions that had a good answer.  Because of this, they should remain different questions, even if they are ***identical*** except for the jurisdiction.